# How to read character in a file 1 by 1 c#

Tags: c#, filestream

I want my program to read a text file all characters 1 by 1 and whereever it finds a double-quote ("), it adds a semicolon before that inverted comma. For eg we have a paragraph in a text file as follow:

> This is a paragraph which conains lots and lots of characters and some
> names and dates. My name "Sam" i was born at "12:00" "noon". I live in
> "anyplace" .

Now I want the output to be as follows:

> This is a paragraph which conains lots and lots of characters and some
> names and dates. My name ;"Sam;" i was born at ;"12:00;" ;"noon;". I
> live in ;"anyplace;" .

It should open the file using file stream then reads character and then adds semicolon where it finds quotes. And the output should be equal to textbox1.Text.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            char ch;
            int Tchar = 0;
            StreamReader reader;
            reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\user1\Documents\data.txt");
            do
            {
                ch = (char)reader.Read();
                Console.Write(ch);
                if (Convert.ToInt32(ch) == 34)
                {
                    Console.Write(@";");
                }
                Tchar++;
            } while (!reader.EndOfStream);
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine(Tchar.ToString() + " characters");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output:

> This is a paragraph which conains lots and lots of characters and some
> names and  dates. My name ";Sam"; i was born at ";12:00"; ";noon";. I
> live in ";anyplace";  . 154 characters

I want that semicolon before the quotes. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: inverted comma? you mean quotes (`"`)?

Comment: @DarkoKenda isnt that big, just use the example i gave above and assume thats my file data.

Comment: @MarcB yeah i am talking about quote. I showed the example and output above

Comment: @MarcB Depends on whether you're speaking English [or English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark). :)

Comment: Something else: Instead of `if (Convert.ToInt32(ch) == 34)` you can simply say `if (ch == '"')`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swap the order of the operations:

```
    if (Convert.ToInt32(ch) == 34)
    {
        Console.Write(@";");
    }
    Console.Write(ch);
```

e.g. don't write the original character until AFTER you've decided to output a semicolon or not.

Comment: i feel stupid. I thought with this we can't add semicolon if first character is ( " ), thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try `ch = (char)reader.Peek();`

This will read tell you the next character without reading it. You can then use this to check if it is a " or not an insert : accordingly

```
if (Convert.ToInt32((char)read.Peek()) == 34) Console.Write(@";")
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you *have* to read in character by character?  The following code will do the whole thing as a block and return you a list containing all your lines.

```
var contents = File.ReadAllLines (@"C:\Users\user1\Documents\data.txt")
                   .Select (l => l.Replace ("\"", ";\""));
```

Comment: i want it to read character by character, thats the whole point of question.

Comment: Fair enough, it just seems unnecessarily inefficient is all.

Comment: @Andrew depends tbh ... `ReadAllLines` loads the entire file into memory first while going through a stream it doesn't

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace getto
{
  class Program
  {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         var path = @"C:\Users\VASANTH14122018\Desktop\file.v";

         string content = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.UTF8);
        Console.WriteLine(content);
        //string helloWorld = "Hello, world!";
        foreach(char c in content)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c);
            }
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: file.v contains the following

Comment: This
is some text
to test
Reading