# Read large text file until a certain string

Tags: .net, string, file, large-files

I have a large string separated text file (not single-char seperated) like this:

> first data[STRING-SEPERATOR]second data[STRING-SEPERATOR] ...

I don't want to load the entire file in the memory because of its size (~250MB). If I read the entire file with `System.IO.File.ReadAllText` i get an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Therefore I want to read the file until the first appereance of `[STRING-SEPERATOR]`, then proceed with the next string. It's like to "take" the `first data` off the file, process it and the go on with the `second data` which is now the first data of the file.

The `System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine()` doesn't help me because the contents of the file is one line.

Have you got an idea how to read a file until a certain string in .NET?

I hope for some ideas, thank you.

Comment: Is `[STRING-SEPERATOR]` a single character or a string of characters?

Comment: It's a string of characters.

Comment: How long is `[STRING-SEPERATOR]` and how long can it be between each successive `[STRING-SEPERATOR]`?

Comment: `[STRING-SEPERATOR]` is a GUID. I can be about 100 charactars between the seperators.

Comment: Is it always the same `Guid`?

Comment: Yes, it's always the same GUID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your replies. Here's the function I wrote in VB.NET:

```vb
Public Function ReadUntil(Stream As System.IO.FileStream, UntilText As String) As String
            Dim builder As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
            Dim returnTextBuilder As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
            Dim returnText As String = String.Empty
            Dim size As Integer = CInt(UntilText.Length / 2) - 1
            Dim buffer(size) As Byte
            Dim currentRead As Integer = -1

            Do Until currentRead = 0
                Dim collected As String = Nothing
                Dim chars As String = Nothing
                Dim foundIndex As Integer = -1

                currentRead = Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                chars = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer, 0, currentRead)

                builder.Append(chars)
                returnTextBuilder.Append(chars)

                collected = builder.ToString()
                foundIndex = collected.IndexOf(UntilText)

                If (foundIndex >= 0) Then
                    returnText = returnTextBuilder.ToString()

                    Dim indexOfSep As Integer = returnText.IndexOf(UntilText)
                    Dim cutLength As Integer = returnText.Length - indexOfSep

                    returnText = returnText.Remove(indexOfSep, cutLength)

                    builder.Remove(0, foundIndex + UntilText.Length)

                    If (cutLength > UntilText.Length) Then
                        Stream.Position = Stream.Position - (cutLength - UntilText.Length)
                    End If

                    Return returnText
                ElseIf (Not collected.Contains(UntilText.First())) Then
                    builder.Length = 0
                End If
            Loop

            Return String.Empty
    End Function
```

C#

```
public static string ReadUntil(System.IO.FileStream Stream, string UntilText)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    System.Text.StringBuilder returnTextBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    string returnText = string.Empty;
    int size = System.Convert.ToInt32(UntilText.Length / (double)2) - 1;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size + 1];
    int currentRead = -1;

    while (currentRead != 0)
    {
        string collected = null;
        string chars = null;
        int foundIndex = -1;

        currentRead = Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        chars = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer, 0, currentRead);

        builder.Append(chars);
        returnTextBuilder.Append(chars);

        collected = builder.ToString();
        foundIndex = collected.IndexOf(UntilText);

        if ((foundIndex >= 0))
        {
            returnText = returnTextBuilder.ToString();

            int indexOfSep = returnText.IndexOf(UntilText);
            int cutLength = returnText.Length - indexOfSep;

            returnText = returnText.Remove(indexOfSep, cutLength);

            builder.Remove(0, foundIndex + UntilText.Length);

            if ((cutLength > UntilText.Length))
                Stream.Position = Stream.Position - (cutLength - UntilText.Length);

            return returnText;
        }
        else if ((!collected.Contains(UntilText.First())))
            builder.Length = 0;
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: This looks good, but how do you start from a particular position?

Answer (score 2):

This should help you.

```
private IEnumerable<string> ReadCharsByChunks(int chunkSize, string filePath)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize]; 
        int currentRead;
        while ((currentRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, chunkSize)) > 0)
        {
            yield return Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer, 0, currentRead);
        }
    }
}

private void SearchWord(string searchWord)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var chars in ReadCharsByChunks(2, "sample.txt"))//Can be any number
    {
        builder.Append(chars);

        var existing = builder.ToString();
        int foundIndex = -1;
        if ((foundIndex = existing.IndexOf(searchWord)) >= 0)
        {
            //Found
            MessageBox.Show("Found");

            builder.Remove(0, foundIndex + searchWord.Length);
        }
        else if (!existing.Contains(searchWord.First()))
        {
            builder.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

StreamReader.Read has some overloads that might help you.
Try this:

```
int index, count;
index = 0;
count = 200; // or whatever number you think is better
char[] buffer = new char[count];
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("Path here");
while (sr.Read(buffer, index, count) > 0) { 
    /*
    check if buffer contains your string seperator, or at least some part of it 
    if it contains a part of it, you need check the rest of the stream to make sure it's a real seporator
    do your stuff, set the index to one character after the last seporator.
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A text file can also be read character-wise, as describe in [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618341/how-to-read-character-in-a-file-1-by-1-c-sharp). For searching for a certain string, you would have to use some manually implemented logic which can search the desired string based on a character-wise input, which can be done with a state machine.